# how many possible 5 char codes can you make with letters 'abcde' such that no char can be used more than twice and no char can be adjacent to itself

Tags: combinatorics

What I have done so far: I broke up the problem into no repeating characters, one repeating character, two repeating characters.

None: 5! ways to arrange abcde with distinct characters

one repeating: $\binom{5}{4} * 4 * (\frac{5!}{2!} - 4!)$. This comes from choosing 4 characters out of the 5 to use (one will repeat) and then choosing one of those to repeat. Then, I multiply this by the number of arrangements which I got by finding the number of indistinguishable permutations and subtracting 4! arrangements where the repeating character is adjacent to itself.

two repeating:  $\binom{5}{3} * 3 * (\frac{5!}{2!2!} - 3!)$ using the same logic as above.

When I add the three cases together, I get 1560 ways. Would appreciate if someone could let me know if this approach is right. Thank you

Comment: For the first and second case, I got the same result as yours. But for the last case, I got $282$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should post this as a comment but I don’t have enough reputation.
I think you are almost correct, except the last number. It should be -18 not -6 in the end. You have 18 cases having adjacent same letters: aabcb, baabc, baacb, similar three more, switch a and b to get 6 more, then caabb, aacbb, aabbc, similar three more by switching a and b.